# Question about power supply's power transistor amps requirement

Tags: power-supply, transistors

I'm studying some simple power supplies for my electronic experiments. In some diagrams, they use 78xx IC as voltage regulator, while attaching a power transistor to handle more amps since 78xx like 7812 can't handle more than 1A. I understand that. What I don't understand is this: in an explanation it is said to use more than one TIP2955 to handle current greater than 3A...but...that transistor datasheet says Ic Max is 15A. Ok, that's its max, but can't it handle 6A? or 8A? those figures are well below 15A max. I don't understand that part. And then, ***if my transformer can yield up to 6A max, for instance, why I couldn't use a power transistor with Ic max just an amp or two greater than 6A?*** At the end, the load won't get more than the PS can supply.

What's the rule between both? I know some have the criteria that capacitors, for instance, should be used x2 its working power, so in a 12v circuit, use at least a 25v capacitor (although I have seen in 12v car devices they use 16v).

Here a screenshot of what I was reading

[image]

Who limits this circuit to be "3 amps"? is it the transformer, right? it uses 1n5404 diodes, 3A, but afaik diodes doesn't limit current. *So I'm very confused* :(

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing here that *limits* the current. That is, there's no current-limit circuitry; the current limit you're talking about is a limit that *you* must obey to avoid damage to the circuit.

The limit is due to the diodes, because drawing more than 3 A continuously will be exceeding their ratings.

The part about putting another transistor to increase the current is **wrong**, by the way. If the transistor was the limiting factor, that would be possible, but the TIP2955 is rated for 15 A. You would need more than one transistor if you were pulling more than 15 A, but you would also need different diodes in that case.

Comment: No no, what I mean is: if the transformer and the diodes are say, 6A...why do I need a 15 A transistor?

Comment: @AramAlvarez You don't, but it certainly doesn't hurt.

Comment: so using a transistor rated the same amps the transformer suffice? or should it be how many amps greater as to be "safe" it won't burn?

Comment: @AramAlvarez You should rate everything a little higher than what you intend to actually use it at, unless you're willing to put in the work to be *absolutely certain* it will survive (which includes doing thermal calculations and maybe even thermal modeling, because a lot of this depends on how well the heatsinking is done).

Comment: @AramAlvarez You could probably just use a transistor rated the same, say 6 amps. Since you already have to stay away from the 6 amp max of the diodes there is no need to go higher. And as Math Keeps Me Busy said the transistor will not be on constantly, and therefore could probably handle more than its rated current. (Although you wouldn't want to do that)

Answer (score 1):

> in an explanation it is said to use more than one TIP2955 to handle current greater than 3A...but...that transistor datasheet says Ic Max is 15A.

If a transistor has a maximum Ic rating of 15 A, that does NOT mean that you can run 15 A through it *regardless* of Vce. You can probably run 15 A through it if the transistor is *saturated*, i.e. used as a switch. However, the transistor in this circuit is not used as a switch, and is not in saturation.

If 9 VDC is applied to the inputs of the rectifier bridge, the outputs will see something like 9 - (2)(0.7) or 7.6 V. Since the output of the regulator is 5V, Vce across the pass transistor will be 7.6-5 = 2.6 V. If the current through the pass transistor is 3 A, the  power dissipated by the transistor will be 2.6 x 3 = 7.8 watts. Enough to require a heatsink. However, if you tried putting 15 A through the transistor, the power dissipated would become 2.6 x 15 = 39 W. In that calculation lies the reason for why it is suggested that if you want more than 3 A output, use multiple pass transistors. For safe operation of your transistor, you must comply not only with maximum Ic rating, but also maximum power dissipation rating, and the maximum junction temperature rating.

Comment: (Neither 7 V AC + 2.2 mF nor 9 V DC would result in 9 V RMS at the bridge output - say 7.5 V from 9 V DC, and 6 V from 7 V AC, with dips way down below 5 V - see [PStechPaul's simulation results](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/664059/274544). But quite right, what results in needing high current capable transistors is the need to dissipate the heat without excessive junction and/or case temperature. TIP2955 will be about 1.4 K/W, + on the order of 0.3 for mounting, + heat sink - 4.3 k/W max. for 12 W and a temperature rise of 80 K. Or < 4 K/W for the transistor and a bigger heat sink.

Comment: @greybeard, you are quite right. I neglected the the 2 diode voltage drops, and they do make a significant difference in this case. I may amend my answer at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little more complicated for a power supply as shown in the OP's circuit. Here is a simulation of a 7.4 VAC transformer into a full wave bridge with a 2200 uF capacitor and a 2 ohm load. Note that the raw output voltage is about 6 VRMS, but varies between about 8 volts and 4 volts. And although each diode is only conducting half the time, its RMS current is just about 3 ARMS, which is about the same as the current through the load. So to obtain a regulated 5 VDC output, a transformer with a much higher output voltage would be needed, and a much larger capacitor to reduce the ripple so that it never drops below about 7 volts, if the regulator has a 2 V dropout.

[image: Raw power supply 7VAC 6VDC 3A]

Here is a simple regulated 5 VDC supply with a 3 A load. Notice that now the current through the diodes is 3.4 ARMS.

[image: 5 VDC regulated power supply]

Answer (score 0):

The load you connect to the 5V circuit's output will determine the current.  So for a 5V circuit rated at 3A do not use a load below 5V/3A = 1.67 Ohms.

As shown the circuit has no current limit. If the load tries to draw more current than the weakest component can handle that component may burn out.

Note that the 7805 component, if it were used on it's own, does have a thermal protection that will shut itself down at a certain temperature.  So this would be sort of a current/power limiter.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for using parallel pass transistors in a power supply is what's called *beta droop*. Transistors tend to have lower \$h_{FE}\$ at higher currents, so it takes more base current to drive them.

Looking at a [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1506769.pdf) for the 2N2955, we find the graph of DC current gain in *Figure 2*.

[image]

At 3 A, the gain is around 55, at 10 A the gain is around 20, at 15 A it's going to be even less, but we'll give it the benefit of the doubt and use 20.

For 3 A this translates to a base current of 54.5 mA. Using 5 transistors would then take 273 mA base current.

A single transistor at 15 A would need 750 mA, nearly three times as much. And where does the base current come from? From the regulator IC, so if you've got a 1 A regulator you're getting close to it's rating.

Another thing you need to watch is the Safe Operating Area.
[image]

Here we see that at 15 A, the \$V_{CE}\$ limit is 6 V limiting your input voltage to 11 V, while at 3 A the \$V_{CE}\$ limit is 30 V, so it's got much more room to breathe. Of course this is all using data sheet values which tend to be a bit conservative, but it gives an illustration of the concept.

I've always recommended linear supplies use one pass transistor for every 5 A of output current, and you'll find commercial supplies stay pretty close to that. I've got a 50 A supply sitting here that has 8 x 20 A transistors, so 6.25 A each. That's for supplies that have another power transistor driving the bases of the pass transistors, but using a three terminal regulator limits the available base drive a bit more, which is possibly why they recommended 3 A per transistor.